# Diablo III Latest Patch Breaks Sockets?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced a complete lack of socket enchantment on amulets and rings after the latest patch.

It seems before the patch I was able to convert a property to a socket with minimal retries.  Now, it seems like I *never* get a socket even after 20-30 retries.

Comment: I have successfully added sockets to jewelry during Season 3. So I guess you just had bad luck.

Comment: I have had both bad and good streaks of rerolling, it's how it's always been. Sometimes it takes 1 reroll to get what you want, sometimes you won't get it after 50+ rerolls, that's just how RNG works.

Comment: In the worst case an Amulet can have 19 primary affixes (including all resistance and +% to elemental damage). This means when enchanting, a socket has 1 of 16 chance to roll. Hence, the chance to *NOT* get a Socket in 10 tries is 52,4%. In 20 tries - still 27,5%. In 30 tries - still 14,4%. Not succeeding in something with 85,6% probability is a bit too early to say the game is broken :-)

Comment: Just recently I got a new amulet (*with* elemental damage, so that's 1 of 13 chance), and burned through all of my 38 Souls with no luck. Then, after farming more, I came back and got a Socket on the first try :-)

Comment: @OrcJMR That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Studoku Well... yeah, indeed :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just having bad luck, but your specific amulet may be especially bad for rerolls.

Different affixes have a different roll probabilities based on their "weights", discussed [here](http://www.diablofans.com/news/48108-datamined-affix-chances-for-enchanting-rend-hotfix). Most of 16 affixes available on Amulets are of same weight, with +X Damage being 1.5 times as probable, Main Stat and Vitality - 4 times, and +% Elemental Damage TEN times as probable as 12 others.

Let us take two cases: an average one and a bad one. Average would be you having Elemental Damage (x10), Mainstat (x4) and CHC (x1), and trying to reroll Regen (x1). That means your chance to get a socket is **1 of 16.5** (weight of socket against the sum of all rollable affix weights). Bad case would be an amulet with Mainstat (x4), CHC (x1), CHD (x1), and rolling off IAS (x1). That puts your chance to **1 in 25.5**! So, it all boils to the following probability table:

```
                Chance to            Chance to fail for
 Weights    succeed on 1st try    10,... 20,... 30 times in a row
---------          ----          -----  -----  -----
1 to 16.5          6.1%          53.5%  28.6%  15.3% 
1 to 25.5          3.9%           67%   44.9%  30.1%
```

You are just having bad luck, and not even that bad - even with maximum probability (having +Elem, Mainstat, Vit) failing 30 times in a row is 9.9%, while succeeding on the first try only 7.4%. If you indeed rolled a socket on first try quite often before, consider this a karmic payback :-)

Less-important-than-before **practical advice**:
After you enchant and item and lock in its remaining properties, your affix weight sum is fixed forever. So the only way to increase your chances is to keep as many "heavier" properties locked as possible, and rerolling "lighter" one. Of course, you usually want that Elemental damage on your Amulet anyway, but if you're thinking of rolling off either Element or something "light", remember that it will cost you approximately 50% more materials to get a Socket if you have to brave the Elements for it.

Comment: Sorry but the calculation is wrong, the probability for each affixes are weighted : [you can take a look at this reddit thread which explains it in detail](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/288xch/datamined_rarity_of_all_affixes_calculating_your/). You have probably noticed that for example, getting elite damage on weapon is way harder than main stat or vitality. Same goes for some secondary affixes like chance to slow on hit which pop way less often than +%gold or health globe pickup radius. So the idea behind your post (IE badluck) is correct however the calculation is not.

Comment: @WizardLizard why, thanks, no reason to be sorry! I am kinda ashamed of not having thought of such a possibility (and I'm having some "ah, that's why..." thoughts now :-). Will recalculate as soon as I'm at a PC.

Comment: @WizardLizard This turned out to be a tremendous improvement to the answer and its practical usefulness. Maybe we should rename the question to "how do I Enchant for a Socket" or "why can't I roll a Socket" to improve discoverability? Do you happen to have any info on what perople search for?

Comment: I was with you until the practical advice.  How does rolling the Elemental Damage increase your odds?  You can roll the same stat you are rerolling at a different value.  Wouldn't it make more sense to roll the low weight stat and keep the high weight stats on because they couldn't roll again?  I.E. reroll IAS on an amulet that has Elemental Damage?

Comment: @Troyen *=slaps himself on the forehead=* You're right. I am not getting much sleep lately, it seems. Of course, affix reing rolled off does roll again, and you either have +Elem among your locked stats or you don't. Thanks for correcting me.